# How to initialize the invoice sequence number every month in OpenERP 7?

Tags: openerp-7

Referencing to this [response](http://help.openerp.com/question/17213/changing-invoice-sequence-numbering-to-include-customer-reference/?answer=17237#post-id-17237)  about changing the invoice sequence format, I want that the number in the sequence must be initialized to 1 every new month. 
For example invoice sequences should be like below:

- in January 2014 :

  - 14/01/001
  - 14/01/002
    .
    .
    .
  - 14/01/xxx
- in February 2014 :

  - 14/02/001
  - 14/02/002
    .
    .
    .
  - 14/02/xxx

And the same logic for the other months.

Thanks for your help.